# Why does Google Analytics show less visits than One&One stats?

Tags: statistics, hosting, google-analytics, analytics

Comparing google analytics results to one&one hosting monthly statics shows a huge discrepancy.

For last month: 
Google shows 1046 visits.
One&one stats show 15304 unique visits.

The google code is in the footer which appears on every page.

I'm aware ga only works with js enabled but to assume that many non js users???

Comment: Two things to check 1) how many bots are in your monthly stats, 2) that you've read Google Analytics' definition of a visit

Comment: @Tim: You should post that as an answer, perhaps with any other items you can think of to add to the list.

Comment: I've edited the title to match the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Analytics is a good indicator of how many humans are visiting your website.

Here are some things to check:

1. how many bots are in your monthly stats? You can usually find something that says `User-Agent` in your stats page. `GoogleBot`, `Slurp`, `msnbot` & others will be visiting every page on your site.
2. that you've read Google Analytics' [definition of a visit](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2007/01/absolute-unique-visitors-versus-new.html).
3. that you have read what your statistics provider means by unique visit. Does that mean [unique visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_visitor), [page view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_view) or something else?

Raw hits on servers can be misleading for a number of reasons..

1. If you have external style sheets & JavaScript etc, they could be counted as a hit in the webserver log
2. RSS feed readers will periodically update without being asked to by a human

Comment: +1 for "read what your statistics provider means by visit". They are probably logging http traffic, which makes it very unlikely they're logging unique visits, and quite likely they're logging pageviews.

Comment: You might also want to check if you have any `<img>` tag with an empty `src`. Some browsers request the same page when they encounter such tags. Imagine if you have a dozen such tags.

Answer (score 1):

Check the page views in Google Analytics - it's possible that 1&1 is tracking unique page views instead of the actual visits.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics works for almost all users (I believe less than 5% have JS disabled). I have had the same discrepancy, in my case the difference was zeroed out when I took into account the bots (which server-side statistics often take into account, as they produce http-requests). You probably have the same "problem".

Neither stats are wrong, they just count different things. Google Analytics is the more "accurate", i.e. the numbers you want to take a look at. The hosting stats, which look only at http requests, often without filtering, are less interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Blogger, and probably other sites, serve a different page template or skin to mobile visitors. In my case, that template didn't contain the google analytics snippet of code and so those hits were uncounted, until I noticed and fixed it.