# Google Analytics shows less pageviews then web server logging?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I implemented google analytics with image tracking method to my mobile website.I found difference b/w page views and unique visitors.Google analytics shows less page views and unique visitors then web server logging.
Please help.

Comment: This is quite common depending on your weblogging setup. Do they remove bots, for example? There are loads of configuration issues when comparing those two. My suggestion: Don't.

Comment: @MrSponge Yes,I filtered bots(Google,Facebook,Bing) from the web server logging.But still GA shows less pageviews and unique visitors then my filtered logging.please help me out

Comment: Is this related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384260/why-does-google-analytics-show-less-visits-than-oneone-stats)